# I want to select a particular list of words containing certain characters using php

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to select a particular list of words in a paragraph containing certain characters

$query_search_text= "SELECT * FROM para where para_main='%text_words'";

I tried using the % sign, but it does not work.  It works if I give in the full text.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$query_search_text= "SELECT * FROM para where para_main LIKE '%text_words%'";
```

Comment: yes, silly me 

thanks

I can accept this answer only after 12 minutes???
I need to accept it now, send me a pm or something so that I remember to accept

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is just a  wildcard, and is valid only for a `LIKE` comparison. The query you've written will select all rows where `para_main` **begins** with the string "text_words".

If you want to allow other characters both before **and** after, you'll have to use:

```
$query_search_text= "SELECT * FROM para where para_main LIKE '%text_words%'";
```

Comment: not sure about mysql, but in standard SQL you have to use LIKE for the wildcards to be used and not =

Comment: Good catch. The eye sees what it wants to see, I guess. I've edited to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually!

```
$query_search_text = "SELECT * FROM para where para_main LIKE '%text_words%'";
```

I also would advise you is too look at FullText searching.
http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM para WHERE para_main LIKE '%text_words%'
```